# Result set update error

Tags: java, jdbc

I wrote a simple code for scrollable resultset.But it gives me an error.

**code:**

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Scrollable_Resultset {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("user", "system");
    p.put("password", "password");

    DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe",p);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from EMPLOYEE");

    System.out.println("Displaying all the rows of the result set forward");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(3));
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }//end of while
    System.out.println("****************");

    System.out.println("Printing resultset in reverse order");
    rs.last();//go to last row
    while(rs.previous())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(3));
        System.out.println("--------------");
    }//end of while
    System.out.println("****************");

    System.out.println("Printing only 1st row");
    rs.first();
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
    System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(3));
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("****************");

    System.out.println("Printing 3rd row of original data set");
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
    System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    System.out.println(rs.getInt(3));
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("****************");

    System.out.print("No of rows before modification: ");
    rs.last();
    System.out.println(rs.getRow());
    System.out.println("****************");

    System.out.println("Updating 3rd row");
    rs.absolute(3);
    rs.updateInt(1, 999);
    rs.updateString(2,"John");
    rs.updateInt(3, 99000);
    rs.updateRow();
    System.out.println("****************");

    System.out.println("Inserting a new row");
    rs.moveToInsertRow();
    rs.updateInt(1, 99);
    rs.updateString(2,"Michael");
    rs.updateInt(3, 909);
    rs.insertRow();
    System.out.println("Deleting the 6th row");
    rs.absolute(6);
    rs.deleteRow();
    System.out.println("****************");
    con.close();
}
```

}

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for read only    resultset: updateInt
at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.BaseResultSet.updateInt(BaseResultSet.java)
at jdbc.Scrollable_Resultset.main(Scrollable_Resultset.java:64)
```

It gives error when I try to update data although I have used **ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE**.
Can any one please let me know what is the reason for the same?

Comment: You can't do what you're trying to do by modifying a result set. You need to execute a SQL query to modify data.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta `Resultset` can be used to modify data, but only if the `ResultSet` sensitivity, concurrency and other datasource requirements for updatable result sets are fullfilled

Comment: I didn't know that. I guess you never stop learning. Thanks! Anyway, as per the response by @Pyranja I wouldn't trust the JDBC driver to do this kind of stuff. Writing a custom query is not that difficult. Actually I wouldn't even use that but JPA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reason is you are using `Select` query and trying to perform `Update` operation

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from EMPLOYEE");
```

and another point is **"SELECT *"** makes **Resultset** as **ReadOnly**

If you want to perform update operation then you need to specify columns in the **Select** Query

Answer (score 2):

See the [Oracle JDBC documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/java.121/e17657/resltset.htm#JJDBC28615).

The Oracle JDBC driver will attempt to downgrade the returned `ResultSet`, if the given query is not suitable for the requested ResultSet type. In your case, using the `*` wildcard may prevent the creation of an updatable ResultSet (there are more restrictions, check the documentation). To verify the cause, you should use the `getWarnings()` method of the ResultSet. The Oracle JDBC driver should have set a warning, if it had to downgrade.

The recommended workaround is using a table alias like:

```
SELECT t.* FROM employee t
```

Note : If you intend to use this mechanism in a (critical) application, make sure to study the documentation carefully. For example, updating through ResultSets silently ignores conflicts. Judging from this, I would not be surprised if there are more pitfalls lurking in the JDBC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Include below change

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select EMPLOYEE.* from EMPLOYEE");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few possibilities:

- **Bad driver**: ensure the proper driver
- The "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE" uses **wildchar** and Oracle doesn't know the exact order of the columns please specify the exact list of the columns and the `ROWID` column

  SELECT ROWID, ... from ENPLOYEE E